# In-circuit MOSFET testing

Tags: mosfet, testing, powermosfet

Can I test a MOSFET in-circuit using the multimeter? I have an N-channel MOSFET with a minimum of 3 V Vgs(th).

Update: Adding schematics for clarity:

[image]

Thanks,
Nithin

Comment: The common way of MOSFET check (using diode check of DMM) may not work if there's a lower impedance path in parallel with the MOSFET's gate-source and drain-source (e.g. a 10k resistor placed across the gate-source).

Comment: The answer depends upon the rest of the circuit. Post a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Depends, if it for instance is in parallel with something shorted, for example Vcc to GND, your MOSFET will appear to measure bad as well. But normally you are able to measure the source-drain body diode as well as source-gate.

Comment: I've added schematics for clarity.

Comment: A minimum Vgs is the gate-source voltage that causes the Mosfet to conduct only 0.25mA so it is almost turned off. Don't you want the Mosfet to turn on much more?